# c ++ dynamic array and input string

Tags: c++

I am new to pointers and I was wondering if someone can take a look at my code and tell me why I am getting an error " invalid conversion from Char to Char;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int stringlenght;
    string  input;

    cout << "Please enter a  string >";
    getline(cin,input);
    cout << "You entered: " << input  << endl << endl;

    stringlenght=input.length();
    cout << stringlenght;

    char *inputArray[stringlenght];
    for (int i=0; i < stringlenght; i ++) {
        inputArray[i]=input[i];
    }

    //system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Lots of C people abbreviate the word "length" to "len", because nobody can ever remember how to spell it.

Comment: thank you, but this is not a spelling contest here.

Comment: If you wanna use pointer, why not use C? Use a vector. It is 2012 this year. PS. You created an array of pointers, not an array of char.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm *pretty* sure that's not the reason.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I always get crappy people like kerrey on stackoverflow, they could be so discouraging  and have no respect for newbies

Comment: If you don't need to modify `inputArray` declare and define it as `const char *inputArray = input.c_str();`.  Either that or just use input.c_str() by itself.  Of course you do need to make sure the `input` string has te same lifetime as `inputArray` if you do that.

Comment: @texasbruce thanks bruce, I actually prefer  vectors, but this is for a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example is that you have declared inputArray as an array of pointers to characters, and therefore inputArray[i] will be a pointer to a character.

What you are trying to do is assign the pointer at the i:th position in inputArray a character value.

What I think you would like to do is to declare inputArray as:

```
char *inputArray = new char[length];

... your loop ...

delete []inputArray;
```

This instead creates one pointer, and makes it point to a contigous area in memory where you can store characters, and therefore the type of inputArray[i] will be char instead of char *.

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

```
inputArray[i]=input[i];
```

Since `inputArray` is an array of `char*` and not `char` types, you can't assign a pointer the actual `char` type rvalue that is being returned by the `operator[]` method of the `string` type when used on the right-hand side of the assignment operator. The pointer-type needs to be assigned an actual address value. Try changing it to:

```
inputArray[i]=&input[i];
```

Keep in mind that if you do this, any operation on the `string` object could invalidate these stored pointers in the `inputArray` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your line
`char *inputArray[stringlenght];`
defines an array of pointers. Aren't you trying just to define an array of char instead, that is, `char inputArray[stringlenght];`?

In this case, copying elements of your input into your inputArray would work, as you would be copying a char into a char.